# Broken image in Django

Tags: python, html, django, image, broken-image

*im getting a broken image i tried almost everything looked at a lot of questions but still not working*

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static_files")

]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('products/', views.all, name='products')
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**the html file**

```
{% for item in product.productimage_set.all%}
{% if item.featured %}
        <div><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image }}"/></div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "broken image", like it isn't loading?, have you tried `<img src="{{ 
image.url }}">`  ?

Comment: you should provide the models also. did you tried with `{{ item.image.url }}`?

Comment: the ```{{ item.image.url }}```  worked thanks a lot